# Two tables left join syntax

Tags: mysql, sql

Help, I need to use a left join. I have two tables;
Horse_table, which has horse_id, name.
Entry_Table, which has horse_id, place.
I need to list the horse_id and name for the horses that have never won a first place. Order by horse_id.

Here is what i have;

```
Select a.horse_id, a.name,
COALESCE ('place'>=1) as 'Never Won First Place'
From horse a LEFT JOIN entry b
ON (a.horse_id=b.horse_id)
AND (b.horse_id=a.name)
Where Horse_id<=502
ORDER by Horse_id;
```

The problem with this is it returns all horses, and not the ones that it should, I have tried using `Where b.place>=1` but it does not return any results.

Comment: Did you try switching the table in your From clause?  Select ... From entry b LEFT JOIN horse a ON (b.horse_id=a.horse_id) Where place >= 1

Comment: I think you should remove `AND (b.horse_id=a.name)` from query.

Comment: Proper DDL's are always useful.

Comment: You need to show sample data, and explain why you think you need a left join.

Comment: Also, are you sure you understand the purpose of the `COALESCE` function?

Comment: Thanks for your input. i now have Select DISTINCT a.horse_id,a.name as 'never won first place'FROM horse a LEFT JOIN entry b ON (a.horse_id=b.horse_id) WHERE b.place>1 ORDER by horse_id

Comment: @user2991848. If the horse has two records in ENTRY, he will show twice and one of them was place = 1, you will still get that horse. In the other hand, if you use something similar to the query i wrote below, you'll get only the ones that never have place = 1

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT a.horse_id,
  a.NAME
FROM horse a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT horse_id, min(place) 
  FROM ENTRY
  GROUP BY horse_id
  HAVING MIN(place) > 1
) b ON a.horse_id = b.horse_id
ORDER BY Horse_id;
```

You JOIN the horse table with the best position he has ever finished (MIN(PLACE)) as long as that position is not 1st place.

Answer (score 0):

List all horse id and horse name whose place is greater than 1 (means never got first position).

```
Select 
    a.horse_id, a.name,
From 
    horse a 
INNER JOIN 
    entry b
ON 
    a.horse_id=b.horse_id
Where 
    b.place>1
ORDER by a.horse_id;
```